# Should a "secret access code" use the same security as a normal password?

Tags: design, security, authentication

Obviously, when you store a password, you should use something similar to bcrypt before you store it in in the database.

But I have a client who wants to add the ability to add a "secret code" to each database entry that a user will have to enter before gaining access to that entry.

The "secret key" isn't exactly as critical as a password, so should I bcrypt this secret code, or does it even need it?

Comment: I'm not sure this question can be answered in a meaningful way. It's your business requirement, so any answer is likely to just be an opinion. Also, it might be more suited to [SecuritySE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Would it matter if you did bcrypt the "secret access code", even if it's not strictly necessary?

Comment: It's the same as with passwords I'd guess. If someone leaks your database table, your functions are open as far as your users have the rights.

Comment: I think you and your client should discuss Authorization as a bussiness aspect in your project.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your client wants to use those "secret codes" as a fine-grained authorization scheme: Only people who are authorized to access those entries should know the corresponding secret code.

If that is the case, then those secret codes serve a similar purpose to passwords and should be subject to the same security standards.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. What is the benefit of not using encryption?

1. Under some circumstances, it can be cheaper to implement and debug.
2. Easier for admins and others to figure out a password / secret access code.

What are the drawbacks of not using encryption?

1. Potential legal liability, depending on the context.
2. Easier for admins and others to figure out a password / secret access code.

Unless this is for an environment where the security must be weak and multiple users must have access to each others passwords (these environments do exist), I think using encryption is clearly the better option.